# Can we solve most of the cosmological questions using the Illustris universe simulation?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, universe, galaxies

The Illustris project (http://illustris-project.org) attempts to simulate the universe in its most accurate form according to their website. With the simulation, they were able to predict the neutral gas distribution in the universe which is a commendable research.

My question is -

Can most of the unsolved mysteries of the universe be solved by such simulations in large scale?

Comment: Galaxy formation certainly ranks among the important astrophysical questions, but it's just one of many problems that need to be solved to get the full cosmological picture. Maybe the most amazing aspect about cosmology is that it spans the full range of scales of the physical universe.

Comment: Given the brief review of the site, seems that this is [Arepo's](http://www.mpa-garching.mpg.de/~volker/arepo/) equivalent to [Gadget](http://www.mpa-garching.mpg.de/gadget/)'s [Millenium simulation](http://www.mpa-garching.mpg.de/galform/virgo/millennium/index.shtml).

Comment: @KyleKanos inaccurate, this is more akin to EAGLE (run on modified P-Gadget3) than Millenium. Millenium was a dark matter simulation, EAGLE and Illustris both include hydrodynamics, and are the first to do so on truly cosmological scales (not counting the simulations run to test and calibrate them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The purpose of computational physics is not to perfectly replicate reality.**

This is an important point that is missed by many, indeed even some people who work in the field. Suppose you had a full and complete description of all the physical laws governing your system, be it a fusion reactor or a star or a galaxy or the whole universe. Now suppose you programmed these laws into a numerically perfect code. You then input as initial conditions a perfect description of your system, down to the atomic level or beyond. Then you let the simulation run.

When the simulation completes, and the output perfectly matches any and all experiments, **what have you learned?** If you have done nothing other than replicate nature, you've learned nothing. You could have just watched nature. In particular, you haven't solved anything.

Physicists strive to achieve *understanding* of the laws of nature. Whether by experiment, pencil-and-paper theory, or simulations, one must always be working toward this goal. Simulations can do this in a number of ways, all of which require putting *thought* into what you are doing with the simulation. For example:

- Test whether certain laws really do connect known initial and final states.
- Determine domains of validity for laws.
- Compare competing effects to see when one or the other dominates the outcome.
- Evolve a final state that can be compared with reality to verify the underlying theory.

If you do a massive cosmological simulation, inputting all the physics you think is relevant and getting an output that looks right, then perhaps you solve a "mystery," but it won't have been a very deep one given the solution will be "we had all the answers in front of us, we just needed to plug in numbers."

More often, simulations do not match observations (or, more subtly, they do but they shouldn't given that relevant physics was omitted). In this case, they are a tool for helping solve mysteries by showing where and how things go wrong.

For a silly example, suppose your model for dark matter is that it consists of chocolate cupcakes too faint to see scattered throughout the universe. A computational physicist might make a simulation that shows how galaxies would be distributed in your model. When everything comes out discrepant with observations, you might conclude that cupcake dark matter is flawed. But that simulation can't then magically tell you what dark matter *is*; you must come up with a new theory. If on the other hand the simulation works perfectly and cupcake dark matter is shown to be correct, wouldn't you as the theorist deserve some of the credit for solving the mystery, rather than just congratulating the person who coded it.

Answer (score 0):

If we put in a computer program the right laws of nature and we scan all the possible initial conditions, then we can get the right answer, with some numerical errors.

The problem is simply that in many areas we don't know exactly what is the underlying physics.
To name some (big) open problems: dark matter, dark energy, CP violation and Matter-Antimatter Asymmetry, gravity in the strong field limit. For primordial cosmology is even worse, a working quantum gravity theory is needed.

In summary: if the early assumptions are wrong, is very likely that the final result will be wrong.